# SELECT OPTION para ver imagen y para ir a URL en misma lista

Tags: select, selectores

Tengo 2 SELECT OPTION diferentes que funcionan perfectamente cada una.

- Una es para seleccionar color y que se vea imagen con la función onchange="showimage(document.forms.SELECT)" :

(Crear una carpeta llamada “COLORES” y meter ahí las imágenes .jpg correspondientes a seleccionar)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<form action="PEDIDO.php" name="SELECT" method="post">

<select name="ELEGIR" value="ELEGIR" onchange="showimage(document.forms.SELECT)">

<script language="javascript">
function showimage( fm ){
if (!document.images) return
ind = fm.ELEGIR.selectedIndex;
sel = fm.ELEGIR.options[ind].value;
document.images.GIF.src = "./COLORES/"+sel;}
</script>

<option selected disabled>ELEGIR</option>

<option value="NEGRO.jpg">NEGRO</option>
<option value="AZUL.jpg">AZUL</option>
<option value="ROJO.jpg">ROJO</option>

</select>

<br>

<img src="IMAGEN.gif" name="GIF">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

- Otra es para seleccionar URL con la función onchange="document.location.href=this.value” :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<form action="PEDIDO.php" name="SELECT" method="post">

<select name="ELEGIR" value="ELEGIR" onchange="document.location.href=this.value">

<option selected disabled>ELEGIR</option>

<option value="https://www.google.es">GOOGLE</option>
<option value="https://www.yahoo.es">YAHOO</option>
<option value="https://www.youtube.es">YOUTUBE</option>

</select>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

HASTA AQUÍ BIEN.

Ahora lo que quiero es juntar todo para que puedas hacer las 2 cosas en la misma lista como esto:

(Crear una carpeta llamada “COLORES” y meter ahí las imágenes .jpg correspondientes a seleccionar)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<form action="PEDIDO.php" name="SELECT" method="post">

<select name="ELEGIR" value="ELEGIR" onchange="showimage(document.forms.SELECT);document.location.href=this.value”>

<script language="javascript">
function showimage( fm ){
if (!document.images) return
ind = fm.ELEGIR.selectedIndex;
sel = fm.ELEGIR.options[ind].value;
document.images.GIF.src = "./COLORES/"+sel;}
</script>

<option selected disabled>ELEGIR</option>

<option value="NEGRO.jpg">NEGRO</option>
<option value="https://www.google.es">GOOGLE</option>
<option value="AZUL.jpg">AZUL</option>
<option value="https://www.yahoo.es">YAHOO</option>
<option value="ROJO.jpg">ROJO</option>
<option value="https://www.youtube.es">YOUTUBE</option>

</select>

<br>

<img src="IMAGEN.gif" name="GIF">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

El error es que solo funciona si seleccionas las URL pero si seleccionas para ver una imagen no se ve porque lo que hace es buscar una URL y te sale el mensaje de “The page cannot be found!”.

Creo que la solución debe estar en crear una fórmula válida juntando las 2 funciones pero no soy capaz de hacerlo funcionar:

onchange= "showimage(document.forms.SELECT) + document.location.href=this.value"

Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo? gracias !!

Comment: No se ayuda a la gente que pega fotos de código y no el propio código, lee las normas.

Comment: Acabo de rectificar, disculpas y por favor ayudarme, muchas gracias

Comment: No hay ningun profesional que pueda echar una mano a ésto? Valentín Sanchez Boto sabes o no?